# Combinations for $2n$ distinct kids in $2n$ distinct seats ( + condition )

Tags: combinations

Given $2n$ labeled kids, $2n$ labeled seats, how many options are there to place the kids in the seats such that every odd-numbered kid with index $1 \leq i \leq n$ sits to the right (not necessarily adjacent) of the kid labeled as $2i.$

I'm stumped, any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Use LaTeX please. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Have you though about using inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: He can not answer you@saulspatz